# whenever select the multiple files through input type file then print the filename and number of pages present in file using React-pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, react-pdf, react-pdf-viewer

I just want to **display multiple filenames** and the **number of pages** present in a particular file. for the number of pages, I'm using the [**react-pdf**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) library

I'm only able to display file names but didn't able to demonstrate/show pdf files when I selected (input file method)

my screen[image]

code is here: -

[codesandbox code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-ellis-10i5tk?file=/src/App.js)

[image: part1]

[image: part2]

[image: part3]

[image: part4]

Comment: Please read [Why shouldn't upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Code%20or%20sample%20data%20in,valuable%20data%20that%20is%20limited.) and share a code sandbox of minimal producible example.

Comment: I know how to enter the code and also, I provided the codesandbox code link but whenever I paste my code then StackOverflow didn't accept if you know the answer then please reply @mc-user